# Domino server : Domino console get locked prompt into strange osgi mode

Tags: lotus-domino, ibm-domino

We have a new installed Domino server 10.0.1FP5
We actually installed 4 of them, all more or less configured and done the same.
But we have an issue with one of the servers concerning the Domino console.
There is no clients installed on the server.
When starting up the Domino console the "command row" is locked in some kind of osgi mode.
It always responds with osgi>

This is how the end of server start look like:

```
[223C:0002-1F0C] 03/27/2023 05:09:40 PM  JVM: Java Virtual Machine initialized.
[223C:0002-1F0C] 03/27/2023 05:09:40 PM  HTTP Server: Java Virtual Machine loaded
[223C:0002-1F0C] 03/27/2023 05:09:41 PM  HTTP JVM: CLFAD0330I: NSF Based plugins are being installed in the OSGi runtime. For more information please consult the log
[223C:0002-1F0C] 03/27/2023 05:09:46 PM  HTTP JVM: Loading OpenNTF Domino API
[223C:0002-1F0C] 03/27/2023 05:09:46 PM  HTTP JVM: Loading org.openntf.domino.xsp library
[223C:0002-1F0C] 03/27/2023 05:09:46 PM  XSP Command Manager initialized

**[223C:000E-180C] 03/27/2023 05:09:46 PM  HTTP JVM: osgi>**

[223C:0037-1BA8] 03/27/2023 05:09:47 PM  HTTP JVM: Preloading XPages classes took 270ms
[223C:0039-1668] 03/27/2023 05:09:47 PM  HTTP JVM: Preloading JSF config took 411ms
[223C:003B-21A0] 03/27/2023 05:09:47 PM  HTTP JVM: Preloading NSF xxxx module took 898ms
[223C:0002-1F0C] 03/27/2023 05:09:49 PM  HTTP Server: Started
```

The server runs and work as expected but for some reason the console is locked into some kind of osgi mode.

When trying to do console commands the answer is as the mode is into osgi

```
ask "show server"

HTTP JVM: gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: show server

[1DAC:009A-215C] 03/22/2023 02:51:12 PM  HTTP JVM: osgi>
```

When I try verify that we are in osgi mode all commends for osgi is answered correctly

```
diag xxxx
```

is giving correct answer as normally below would give by

```
tell http osgi diag xxxx
```

I have tried everything I can think of to "exit" out of osgi> mode, but no luck and have also tried to google it of course.

When accessing the server from another server through Admin client the server responds normally so the issue is only in Domino console.

Anyone have seen this before and more important have nice solution for it.

/Stefan

Comment: Have you opened a case with HCL for this?

Comment: Usually takes to long time for an answer.
Google and the smart community is usually much faster.